# How to replace a string in every file in a directory

Tags: python, xml, string, file, replace

I'm trying to replace with python a string: "XXXXXXXXXXX" with a new string: "ILoveStackOverflow" in every file in a particular folder (all the files in the folder are xml).

My code is as follows:

```
import os, fnmatch

for filename in os.listdir("C:/Users/Francesco.Borri/Desktop/passivo GME"):
if filename.endswith('.xml'):
    with open(os.path.join("C:/Users/Francesco.Borri/Desktop/passivo GME", filename)) as f: 
        content = f.read()
        content = content.replace("XXXXXXXXXXX", "ILoveStackOverflow")
    with open(os.path.join("C:/Users/Francesco.Borri/Desktop/passivo GME", filename), mode="w") as f: #Long Pierre-André answer
        f.write(content)
```

The next step would be to replace a different string: "YYYY" with a number that increases every time. If in my directory there are 10 files and I set the starting number 1, the first file "YYYY" will be replaced with 1, the second file with 2 and so on until 10.

Comment: Start by uploading an example of the XML file. Point to the element that should be replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. When you open the file the second time, you have to open it in writeable mode to be able to write the content.

```
with open(os.path.join("C:/Users/Francesco.Borri/Desktop/passivo GME", filename), 'w') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

Once you fix this, I think the second part of your question is just maintaining a variable whose value you increment everytime you replace the string. You could do it manually (iterate over the string), or use the replace function in a for loop:

```
with open(os.path.join("C:/Users/Francesco.Borri/Desktop/passivo GME", filename)) as f:
        content = f.read()
for i in range(content.count("YYYY")):
    content.replace("YYYY", str(i), 1)  # or str(i+1)
with open(os.path.join("C:/Users/Francesco.Borri/Desktop/passivo GME", filename), 'w') as f:
        f.write(content)
```

Comment: Perfect, It worked. I wasnt very clear but there is one unique "YYYY" string for each file. I simply used an index in order to increase the number in the first cycle. Everything is perfect now

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(os.path.join("C:/Users/Francesco.Borri/Desktop/passivo GME", filename), mode="w") as f:
```

You must open the file on writing mode.